# How to conditionally update a dataframe, from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I load a csv in a DataFrame and get some NaN values.

I want to compute and replace these NaN values with a custom function I have.

Example Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Oct  8 20:44:27 2020

@author: theo
"""

import pandas as pd
import math

def customfunction(arg1):
  arg2 = arg1 * arg1
  arg3 = arg2 + arg1
  return arg1, arg2, arg3

dt = pd.DataFrame([[0, 5, math.nan], [-5, 2, 3], [3, -7, 4]])

for index, row in dt.iterrows():
    if (row.isnull().values.any()):
        (_, arg2, arg3) = customfunction(arg1=row[0]) # Yes the row that contains the NaN values also has the arg1 value I need to compute the rest values
        dt.loc[index,1] = arg2
        dt.loc[index,2] = arg3
```

The above code works... But it is slow can someone suggest something better?

I'm posting a time comparison on a real case with a suggested method (which was 2 times slower)
I want to point out that in the real case the values are taken from a table and are not simply computed. So please use a function definition for you example that returns multiple values.

```
start_time = time.time()

daily1 = daily.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.where(any(x.isna()), (getdaytempartures(date=x[0],ht=hourly)), (x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3]))), axis=1)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
--- 252.25447249412537 seconds ---


start_time = time.time()

for index, row in daily.iterrows():
    if (row.isnull().values.any()):
        (_, tavg, tmin, tmax) = getdaytempartures(date=row['date'], ht=hourly)
        daily.loc[index,'tavg'] = tavg
        daily.loc[index,'tmin'] = tmin
        daily.loc[index,'tmax'] = tmax
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
--- 113.31336617469788 seconds ---

start_time = time.time()
#for key in daily.keys():
daily3 = daily.apply(cf, ht=hourly, axis=1)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
--- 108.97707056999207 seconds ---
```

A few more details. daily has the following columns:  names=['date', 'tavg', 'tmin', 'tmax']
And hourly has the following columns: names=['date', 'time', 'temp']

A sample computing function that returns a row is:

```
def cf(row, ht):
    if row.isnull().values.any():
        dt = ht.loc[ht['date'] == row[0]].dropna()
        row['tmax'] = dt['temp'].max()
        row['tmin'] = dt['temp'].min()
        row['tavg'] = dt['temp'].sum() / dt['temp'].count()
    return row
```

sample data the first ones are the first 30 of each table... Those wont help tbh:

```
daily:

,date,tavg,tmin,tmax
0,1963-01-03,27.3,16.1,33.9
1,1963-01-04,27.3,16.1,33.9
2,1963-01-05,26.7,17.8,35.0
3,1963-01-06,26.7,17.8,33.9
4,1963-01-07,27.6,17.2,33.9
5,1963-01-08,26.9,17.8,33.9
6,1963-01-09,27.3,18.9,33.9
7,1963-01-10,26.8,20.0,35.0
8,1963-01-13,27.3,17.8,33.9
9,1963-01-14,27.2,17.8,33.9
10,1963-01-15,27.9,17.8,35.0
11,1963-01-16,27.5,17.8,35.0
12,1963-01-17,27.5,17.8,36.1
13,1963-01-18,27.6,17.8,33.9
14,1963-01-19,26.9,17.8,35.0
15,1963-01-20,27.3,18.9,35.0
16,1963-01-21,27.6,17.8,35.0
17,1963-01-22,26.0,17.8,35.0
18,1963-01-23,28.1,17.8,33.9
19,1963-01-24,27.6,18.9,32.8
20,1963-01-25,28.3,17.8,33.9
21,1963-01-26,28.1,17.8,35.0
22,1963-01-27,28.5,17.8,35.0
23,1963-01-28,27.7,17.8,36.1
24,1963-01-29,27.9,17.2,35.0
25,1963-01-30,28.1,17.2,37.2
26,1963-02-05,26.1,18.9,33.9
27,1963-02-11,29.2,17.8,33.9
28,1963-02-12,29.3,18.9,36.1
29,1963-02-13,29.7,18.9,36.1

hourly:

,date,time,temp
0,1957-07-01,0,25.0
1,1957-07-01,12,22.2
2,1957-07-01,18,27.2
3,1957-07-02,0,26.1
4,1957-07-02,12,22.2
5,1957-07-02,18,27.8
6,1957-07-03,0,26.1
7,1957-07-03,12,22.2
8,1957-07-03,18,28.9
9,1957-07-04,0,25.0
10,1957-07-04,12,22.2
11,1957-07-04,18,28.9
12,1957-07-05,0,25.0
13,1957-07-05,12,21.1
14,1957-07-05,18,25.0
15,1957-07-06,0,25.0
16,1957-07-06,12,20.0
17,1957-07-06,18,27.8
18,1957-07-07,0,25.0
19,1957-07-07,12,21.1
20,1957-07-07,18,27.8
21,1957-07-08,0,25.0
22,1957-07-08,12,21.1
23,1957-07-08,18,28.9
24,1957-07-09,0,23.9
25,1957-07-09,12,20.0
26,1957-07-09,18,25.0
27,1957-07-10,0,23.9
28,1957-07-10,12,17.8
29,1957-07-10,18,26.1


Hourly 1977-02-20: this is a 1 day example that I used to debug
,date,time,temp
36493,1977-02-20,0,27.0
36494,1977-02-20,1,26.0
36495,1977-02-20,2,26.0
36496,1977-02-20,3,26.0
36497,1977-02-20,11,23.0
36498,1977-02-20,12,23.0
36499,1977-02-20,13,
36500,1977-02-20,14,27.0
36501,1977-02-20,15,29.0
36502,1977-02-20,16,
36503,1977-02-20,17,30.0
36504,1977-02-20,18,32.0
36505,1977-02-20,19,33.0
36506,1977-02-20,20,33.0
36507,1977-02-20,21,32.0
36508,1977-02-20,22,30.0
36509,1977-02-20,23,28.0

daily:
,date,tavg,tmin,tmax
3297,1977-02-20,28.3,,34.0
```

gl and hf... I think it was easier to solve without data though...

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There are two main issues causing the operations to be slow:

  - The first issue is iterating row by row, is always slower than vectorized functions.
  - The second issue is, every iteration requires `min`, `max`, and `mean` to be calculated.
- It's better to group the `'hourly'` dataframe by `'date'`, and then aggregate `min`, `mean`, and `max`, for `'temp'`, creating `hg`.

  - `hg` can then be used to [`pandas.DataFrame.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) `daily`, but the column names of the two dataframes should match.

    - This is an inplace update, so don't assign the update (e.g. `daily = daily.update(hg)` is incorrect).
  - `overwrite=True` will update all values in the dataframe, not just `NaN` values.

    - This is why `overwrite=False` is used to only update the `NaN` values of the dataframe
    - This is why the entire row of data is updated, by sub-setting all the rows with `NaN`, and using `overwrite=True`.
- All iterations are removed, so it should be much faster.
- Also, it's **NEVER** easier to solve the problem without all the information.

### Setup DataFrames

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy

# create sample dataframes; this may us pd.read_csv or something else, as required
daily = pd.DataFrame(daily_data)
hourly = pd.DataFrame(hourly_data)

# convert date to a datetime type for both dataframes
daily.date = pd.to_datetime(daily.date)
hourly.date = pd.to_datetime(hourly.date)

# set date as the index, only for daily
daily.set_index('date', inplace=True)

# sort the daily dataframe
daily.sort_index(inplace=True)

# create a groupby dataframe for date and aggregate metrics on temp
hg = hourly.groupby('date',)['temp'].agg(['mean', 'min', 'max'])

# rename the columns of hg, to match the columns of daily: mean to tavg, min to tmin, max to tmax
hg.columns = ['tavg', 'tmin', 'tmax']
```

- `daily` showing missing values

```py
            tavg  tmin  tmax
date                        
1957-07-07  27.6  17.2  33.9
1957-07-08  25.0   NaN  30.0
1957-07-09  27.3  18.9  33.9
1957-08-05  26.1  18.9  33.9
1957-08-11  29.2  17.8  33.9
1957-08-12  29.3  18.9  36.1
1957-08-13  29.7  18.9  36.1
1977-02-20  28.3   NaN  34.0
```

- `hg` showing daily groups with metrics

```py
                 tavg  tmin  tmax
date                             
1957-07-01  24.800000  22.2  27.2
1957-07-02  25.366667  22.2  27.8
1957-07-03  25.733333  22.2  28.9
1957-07-04  25.366667  22.2  28.9
1957-07-05  23.700000  21.1  25.0
1957-07-06  24.266667  20.0  27.8
1957-07-07  24.633333  21.1  27.8
1957-07-08  25.000000  21.1  28.9
1957-07-09  22.966667  20.0  25.0
1957-07-10  22.600000  17.8  26.1
1977-02-20  28.333333  23.0  33.0
```

### Update only `NaN` values

```py
# this will do an inplace update of only the NaN values; not the entire row
daily.update(hg, overwrite=False)

# result of daily being updated
            tavg  tmin  tmax
date                        
1957-07-07  27.6  17.2  33.9
1957-07-08  25.0  21.1  30.0
1957-07-09  27.3  18.9  33.9
1957-08-05  26.1  18.9  33.9
1957-08-11  29.2  17.8  33.9
1957-08-12  29.3  18.9  36.1
1957-08-13  29.7  18.9  36.1
1977-02-20  28.3  23.0  34.0
```

### Update entire row if there's `NaN`

```py
# select only the rows from daily, containing a NaN
daily_na = daily[daily.isna().any(axis=1)].copy()

# update all the values in the rows
daily_na.update(hg)

# now update daily from daily_na
daily.update(daily_na)

# result of daily being updated
            tavg  tmin  tmax
date                        
1957-07-07  27.6  17.2  33.9
1957-07-08  25.0  21.1  28.9
1957-07-09  27.3  18.9  33.9
1957-08-05  26.100000  18.9  33.9
1957-08-11  29.200000  17.8  33.9
1957-08-12  29.300000  18.9  36.1
1957-08-13  29.700000  18.9  36.1
1977-02-20  28.333333  23.0  33.0
```

### Sample Data

```py
daily_data = {'date': ['1957-07-03', '1957-07-04', '1957-07-05', '1957-07-06', '1957-07-07', '1957-07-11', '1957-07-09', '1957-07-10', '1957-07-13', '1957-07-14', '1957-07-15', '1957-07-16', '1957-07-17', '1957-07-18', '1957-07-19', '1957-07-20', '1957-07-21', '1957-07-22', '1957-07-23', '1957-07-24', '1957-07-25', '1957-07-26', '1957-07-27', '1957-07-28', '1957-07-29', '1957-07-30', '1957-08-05', '1957-08-11', '1957-08-12', '1957-08-13', '1977-02-20', '1957-07-08'],
              'tavg': [27.3, 27.3, 26.7, 26.7, 27.6, 26.9, 27.3, 26.8, 27.3, 27.2, 27.9, 27.5, 27.5, 27.6, 26.9, 27.3, 27.6, 26.0, 28.1, 27.6, 28.3, 28.1, 28.5, 27.7, 27.9, 28.1, 26.1, 29.2, 29.3, 29.7, 28.3, 25.0],
              'tmin': [16.1, 16.1, 17.8, 17.8, 17.2, 17.8, 18.9, 20.0, 17.8, 17.8, 17.8, 17.8, 17.8, 17.8, 17.8, 18.9, 17.8, 17.8, 17.8, 18.9, 17.8, 17.8, 17.8, 17.8, 17.2, 17.2, 18.9, 17.8, 18.9, 18.9, np.nan, np.nan],
              'tmax': [33.9, 33.9, 35.0, 33.9, 33.9, 33.9, 33.9, 35.0, 33.9, 33.9, 35.0, 35.0, 36.1, 33.9, 35.0, 35.0, 35.0, 35.0, 33.9, 32.8, 33.9, 35.0, 35.0, 36.1, 35.0, 37.2, 33.9, 33.9, 36.1, 36.1, 34.0, 30.0]}

hourly_data = {'date': ['1957-07-01', '1957-07-01', '1957-07-01', '1957-07-02', '1957-07-02', '1957-07-02', '1957-07-03', '1957-07-03', '1957-07-03', '1957-07-04', '1957-07-04', '1957-07-04', '1957-07-05', '1957-07-05', '1957-07-05', '1957-07-06', '1957-07-06', '1957-07-06', '1957-07-07', '1957-07-07', '1957-07-07', '1957-07-08', '1957-07-08', '1957-07-08', '1957-07-09', '1957-07-09', '1957-07-09', '1957-07-10', '1957-07-10', '1957-07-10', '1977-02-20', '1977-02-20', '1977-02-20', '1977-02-20', '1977-02-20', '1977-02-20', '1977-02-20', '1977-02-20', '1977-02-20', '1977-02-20', '1977-02-20', '1977-02-20', '1977-02-20', '1977-02-20', '1977-02-20', '1977-02-20', '1977-02-20'],
               'time': [0, 12, 18, 0, 12, 18, 0, 12, 18, 0, 12, 18, 0, 12, 18, 0, 12, 18, 0, 12, 18, 0, 12, 18, 0, 12, 18, 0, 12, 18, 0, 1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
               'temp': [25.0, 22.2, 27.2, 26.1, 22.2, 27.8, 26.1, 22.2, 28.9, 25.0, 22.2, 28.9, 25.0, 21.1, 25.0, 25.0, 20.0, 27.8, 25.0, 21.1, 27.8, 25.0, 21.1, 28.9, 23.9, 20.0, 25.0, 23.9, 17.8, 26.1, 27.0, 26.0, 26.0, 26.0, 23.0, 23.0, np.nan, 27.0, 29.0, np.nan, 30.0, 32.0, 33.0, 33.0, 32.0, 30.0, 28.0]}
```

Comment: Yes, this is useful and could do what I want. Funny enough I made the function to process the hourly data only when necessary (because there are a lot of them) and still processing them all to compute the daily data is faster! That was not intuitive... Anyhow, I think that: dt = ht.loc[ht['date'] == row[0]].dropna() somehow increased the complexity from linear to quadratic. Normally the task I did should be O(N+M) with N the number of daily records and M the number of Hourly records... But the speed seems to make it N*M like if the instruction needs to access all M each time.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

a = np.arange(0, 6, dtype='int32')
b = np.arange(0, 6, dtype='int32')** 2

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b': b})
df.at[[0, 4], 'a'] = None

df
```

---

```
    a   b
0   NaN 0
1   1   1
2   2   4
3   3   9
4   NaN 16
5   5   25
```

---

```
# to avoid the assignment warning
pd.set_option('chained_assignment', None)

is_nan = df['a'].isna()
df['a'][is_nan] = 2 *  df['b'][is_nan]

df
```

---

```
    a   b
0   0   0
1   1   1
2   2   4
3   3   9
4   32  16
5   5   25
```

---

### Another solution

```
df['a'] = df['a'].fillna(2 * df['b'])

df
```

Comment: so apply! I will read and play with it possibly it might do what I want.
Thank you, if it works I will upvote you :-)

Comment: This wont work I am afraid... I need to pass The first column of the Row as an argument while I modify the rest of the columns. From what I understand I Do not have the ROW in your example

Comment: Okay, this works. The time is ~109sec which is not really an improvement from 113sec...

Comment: btw, as you are editing row by row now you do not require the for key ...

Comment: `for loop`, assuming you are updating multiple column using different a arguments for `custom_func`, anyway, I have updated the answer to much simpler one.

Comment: This solution also had some useful information. The solution was given by Trenton but your suggestions are also interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to replace NaNs in the following data frame:

`df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [None, np.nan, 1.0], "col2": [1,2,3]})`

```
0   NaN     1
1   NaN     2
2   1.0     3
```

You can use operations on the entire column instead of on each element in row:

```
df.assign(
    col3 = np.where(df_.isnull().any(axis=1), df_.col2 * df_.col2, df_.col1)
).assign(
    col4 = lambda df_: np.where(df.isnull().any(axis=1), df_.col3 + df_.col2, df_.col1)
)
```

It gives you:

```
0   NaN     1   1.0   2.0
1   NaN     2   4.0   6.0
2   1.0     3   1.0   1.0
```

col3 and col4 are equivalent to your arg2 and arg3 in your example.

`df_.isnull().any(axis=1)` will give you all rows with at least one NaN.

Comment: You are creating a new column in the existing dataframe with the computed value? It could work but the values I check are spread in 3 different columns which would mean adding another 3 new columns.

Comment: Sorry. I thought you want to create new columns with your arg2 and arg3. Misread your example. You can simply change col3 or col4 in my example to col1 if you just want to replace values in the original column.

Comment: I still havent clearly understood your example. I need to pass as a value to my function the first column. I dont see you do that.